# Showing active style box on MS Word 2010

Tags: styles

On MS Word 2003, next to the Font and Font size boxes was one showing the active style. Can I get that on Word 2010? Scrolling through the Styles pane rron the ribbon is wasting a huge amount of time, so I think there must be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Click the little thingie in bottom right corner of the *Styles* pane:

[image: Thingie button with an arrow pointing to it]

A *Styles* window will appear. You can dock it to main window sides by dragging it to them or just leave it floating. It's a bit better than ribbon styles because it shows more styles at once and you can customize what kind of styles is shown (click *Options*).

Comment: Thank you. It sure takes up more landscape than the little box used to and isn't as quick, but it's better than the alternative. I appreciate your help!